# Можно ли так выразить локальные переменные?

Tags: forth

```
: LOC-VAR{ ( N -- ) ALLOT ;
: }LOC-VAR ( N -- ) 1- * ALLOT ;
: L-VAR@   ( N -- ZN ) HERE SWAP - C@ ;
: L-VAR!   ( ZN N -- )  HERE SWAP - C! ;
```

Как-то так...  Существует ли здесь утечка памяти?

Comment: Обращение типа 3 LOC-VAR{ .... 3 }LOC-VAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, такое выражение локальных переменных вполне допустимо, но применимо только в очень ограниченных случаях.

Такая реализация локальных переменных:

1. Допускает утечку, если из блока `LOC-VAR{ ... }LOC-VAR` будет выполнен переход за его пределы:

   a) через `THROW`, или при аппаратном исключении;

   b) через нормальное управление потоком исполнения (например, через `EXIT`, или пересекающий `IF ... THEN`).
2. Нереентерабельна, и неприменима в случае многопоточности при разделяемой области данных `HERE`.

В классической реализации локальных переменных используется та же самая идея вложенного выделения и освобождения памяти; но, память выделяется на стеке возвратов — и это автоматически решает проблемы 1a и 2.

Проблема 1b может решаться по разному, но в любом случае вручную. Одно из решений: обойтись без явного `}LOC-VAR` и обеспечить автоматическое освобождение памяти при выходе путем добавления на стек возвратов адреса слова, которое делает освобождение. Пример такого решения (для простоты, память также выделяется в области данных):

```
: (RELEASE-LOC) ( S: -- R: size -- ) R> NEGATE ALLOT ;
: RESERVE-LOC ( u -- ) CELLS DUP ALLOT R> SWAP >R ['] (RELEASE-LOC) >R >R ; \ ' this tick is just workaround for the highlighter issue
: LOC! ( x i -- ) CELLS NEGATE HERE + ! ;
: LOC@ ( i -- x ) CELLS NEGATE HERE + @ ;

\ испытание
: test ( i -- ) 1 RESERVE-LOC  DUP 0= IF . EXIT THEN   DUP 0 LOC! 1- RECURSE 0 LOC@ . ;
5 test
\ вывод: 0 1 2 3 4 5  Ok
```

Следует отметить, что передача управления через стек возвратов выражается приведеным способом (т.е., в форме `R> ['] XXX >R >R`) если в форт-системе исполнимый токен (`xt`) в тоже время является адресом фрагмента кода. Иначе же исполнимый токен следует преобразовать к адресу фрагмента: `R> ['] XXX >TCODE >R >R` (см. [M.L.Gassanenko, 1998, Open Interpreter: Portability of Return Stack Manipulations](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/euroforth/ef98/gassanenko98b.pdf)).

Comment: Спасибо возьму на вооружение )

Comment: Но естественно возникают проблемы с исп. в циклах, что критично. Да и если значение перетянуть на тот же стек возвратов.

Comment: Да, если (и только если) фрейм выделять на стеке возвратов, то в простейшей реализации возникает чувствительности к указателю стека возвратов (т.е., в приведеном примере ее нету). Решается через  отслеживание изменения глубины стека возвратов стандартыми словами (см. lib/ext/locals.f # `uAddDepth` в SP-Forth), или путем доступа через отдельную переменную (вместо указателя стека возвратов).